# How to show the percentage of uptime of an AWS service on the dashboard of CloudWatch?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-cloudwatch

I want to build a dashboard that displays the percentage of the uptime for each month of an Elastic Beanstalk service in my company.

So I used [boto3 get_metric_data](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/cloudwatch.html#CloudWatch.Client.get_metric_data) to retrieve the *Environment Health* CloudWatch metrics data and calculate the percentage of non-severe time of my service.

```
from datetime import datetime
import boto3

SEVERE = 25

client = boto3.client('cloudwatch')

metric_data_queries = [
    {
        'Id': 'healthStatus', 
        'MetricStat': {
            'Metric': {
                'Namespace': 'AWS/ElasticBeanstalk',
                'MetricName': 'EnvironmentHealth',
                'Dimensions': [
                    {
                        'Name': 'EnvironmentName', 
                        'Value': 'ServiceA'
                    }
                ]
            },
            'Period': 300,
            'Stat': 'Maximum'
        },
        'Label': 'EnvironmentHealth',
        'ReturnData': True
    }
]

response = client.get_metric_data(
    MetricDataQueries=metric_data_queries,
    StartTime=datetime(2019, 9, 1),
    EndTime=datetime(2019, 9, 30),
    ScanBy='TimestampAscending'
    )

health_data = response['MetricDataResults'][0]['Values']
total_times = len(health_data)
severe_times = health_data.count(SEVERE)
print(f'total_times: {total_times}')
print(f'severe_times: {severe_times}')
print(f'healthy percent: {1 - (severe_times/total_times)}')
```

Now I'm wondering how to show the percentage on the dashboard on CloudWatch. I mean I want to show something like the following:

[image]

Does anyone know how to upload the *healthy percent* I've calculated to the dashboard of CloudWatch?

Or is there any other tool that is more appropriate for displaying the uptime of my service?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do math with CloudWatch metrics: 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/using-metric-math.html

You can create a metric math expression with the metrics you have in `metric_data_queries` and get the result on the graph. Metric math also works with GetMetricData API, so you could move the calculation you do into MetricDataQuery and get the number you need directly from CloudWatch.

Looks like you need a number saying what percentage of datapoints in the last month the metric value equaled to 25.

You can calculate it like this (this is the source of the graph, you can use in CloudWatch console on the source tab, make sure the region matches your region and the metric name matches your metric):

```
{
  "metrics": [
    [
      "AWS/ElasticBeanstalk",
      "EnvironmentHealth",
      "EnvironmentName",
      "ServiceA",
      {
        "label": "metric",
        "id": "m1",
        "visible": false,
        "stat": "Maximum"
      }
    ],
    [
      {
        "expression": "25",
        "label": "Value for severe",
        "id": "severe_c",
        "visible": false
      }
    ],
    [
      {
        "expression": "m1*0",
        "label": "Constant 0 time series",
        "id": "zero_ts",
        "visible": false
      }
    ],
    [
      {
        "expression": "1-AVG(CEIL(ABS(m1-severe_c)/MAX(m1)))",
        "label": "Percentage of times value equals severe",
        "id": "severe_pct",
        "visible": false
      }
    ],
    [
      {
        "expression": "(zero_ts+severe_pct)*100",
        "label": "Service Uptime",
        "id": "e1"
      }
    ]
  ],
  "view": "singleValue",
  "stacked": false,
  "region": "eu-west-1",
  "period": 300
}
```

To explain what is going on there (what is the purpose of each element above, by id):

- **m1** - This is your original metric. Setting stat to `Maximum`.
- **severe_c** -  Constant you want to use for your SEVERE value.
- **zero_ts** - Creating a constant time series with all values equal zero. This is needed because constants can't be graphed and the final value will be constant. So to graph it, we'll just add the constant to this time series of zeros.
- **severe_pct** - this is where you actually calculate the percentage of value that are equal SEVERE.

  - `m1-severe_c` - sets the datapoints with value equal SEVERE to 0.
  - `ABS(m1-severe_c)` - makes all values positive, keeps SEVERE datapoints at 0.
  - `ABS(m1-severe_c)/MAX(m1)` - dividing by maximum value ensures that all values are now between 0 and 1.
  - `CEIL(ABS(m1-severe_c)/MAX(m1))` - snaps all values that are different than 0 to 1, keeps SEVERE at 0.
  - `AVG(CEIL(ABS(m1-severe_c)/MAX(m1))` - Because metric is now all 1s and 0s, with 0 meaning SEVERE, taking the average gives you the percentage of non severe datapoints.
  - `1-AVG(CEIL(ABS(m1-severe_c)/MAX(m1)))` - finally you need the percentage of severe values and since values are either severe or not sever, substracting from 1 gives you the needed number.
- **e1** - The last expression gave you a constant between 0 and 1. You need a time series between 0 and 100. This is the expression that gives you that: `(zero_ts+severe_pct)*100`. Not that this is the only result that you're returning, all other expressions have `"visible": false`.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but how can I count the number of SEVERE metrics (EnvironmentHealth value = 25) in the graphed metrics? 
I can't find any functions that can be used to determine if a metric point is equal to a specific number.

Comment: You can calculate it. I updated my answer, let me know if this is what you need.

Comment: Yesterday, my `(zero_ts+severe_pct)*100` shows me `-99.9`, so I changed it to `-(zero_ts+severe_pct)*100`. 
But today, I got `Error in expression e1 [Unsupported type conversion from Scalar to TimeSeries]` error with `(zero_ts+severe_pct)*100` expression. This is strange. Is this a bug of CloudWatch?

Comment: Interesting, works if you collapse all expressions into 1:  `(m1*0+(1-AVG(CEIL(ABS(m1-25)/MAX(m1)))))*100`

Answer (score 0):

Pretty late to the party, but maybe it will benefit others as well.

Dejan's solution didn't work for me and I also couldn't quite wrap my head around what it's trying to accomplish. Maybe there have been some changes to Cloudwatch or Elastic beanstalk since then.

Try the following metric, this should show the uptime correctly:

```
{
"sparkline": true,
"metrics": [
    [ "AWS/ElasticBeanstalk", "EnvironmentHealth", "EnvironmentName", "<env-name>", { "label": "metric", "id": "m1", "visible": false, "stat": "Maximum" } ],
    [ { "expression": "m1 >= 15", "label": "Value for higher than warning", "id": "warning_or_higher", "visible": false } ],
    [ { "expression": "m1 < 15", "label": "Value for lower than warning", "id": "ok", "visible": false } ],
    [ { "expression": "100*RUNNING_SUM(ok)/(RUNNING_SUM(ok)+RUNNING_SUM(warning_or_higher))", "label": "Uptime", "id": "uptime", "visible": true } ]
],
"view": "timeSeries",
"stacked": true,
"region": "<region>",
"period": 300,
"stat": "Average"
}
```

`RUNNING_SUM` ensures that you get back a time series instead of just a single value.

1. `m1` - is the EnvironmentHealth value, which can be: 0 - OK, 1 - INFO, 5 - UNKNOWN, 10 - NO DATA, 15 - WARNING, 20 - DEGRADED, 25 - SEVERE
2. `m1 >= 15` - returns a timeseries where the value is 1 if the condition is true and 0 otherwise. I checked for anything greater then 15, so for statuses WARNING, DEGRADED, SEVERE. By changing this value, you can change the statuses that you take into account
3. `m1 < 15` - This is basically just the second metric negated. This is what you count as "okay"
4. The formula itself: You take the favorable outcome (i.e. environment is okay) and divide it by the sum of all outcomes (i.e. environment is okay + environment is not okay). You get a value back which is between 0 and 1, therefore the multiplication with 100 so you get a percentage.